# Is a VFP uniqueidentifier the same as a Guid?

Tags: sql-server, guid, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I'm converting a foxpro database to SQL Server and some of the keys are VFP-generated unique identifiers - GUIDs I assume. Are these valid uniqueidentifiers?

Can I just use the bytes and convert them easily into a uniqueidentifier in SQL Server?

Thanks,

Craig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it is the same

Answer (score 2):

VFP's unique identifiers are just integers, not GUIDs. By default, they start from 1 and go up by 1.

Comment: According to an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226178.aspx), this answer is wrong: "UNIQUEIDENTIFIER is a GUID data type that stores globally unique identifiers."

Comment: But the unique identifiers in question aren't type UNIQUEIDENTIFIER. They're just a regular Integer field with a property set to make them autoincrement. Visual FoxPro has different data types than SQL Server.

Comment: I'm sure the OP has long since forgotten this conversion project, but wanted to make the point that you _can_ generate GUIDs within FoxPro using links to .NET, and use them as primary keys in tables. He says, "keys are VFP-generated unique identifiers - GUIDs I assume." He does **not** mention auto-increment fields, and although he claims they are _VFP-generated_, they may be generated by _user code_ calling .NET rather than the VFP code itself.